# Key combination to change screen brightness in windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

My external keyboard doesn't have the brightness key but it comes with an fn button. I tried a bunch of key combination with the fn key + the f keys and I found out how to raise the volume up and down (fn+f11 or f12) but not brightness.

I know that the easiest way is to use the laptop's keyboard but mine is a Lenovo yoga 720, so when it folds, you no longer have access to its keyboard so that's why I would really like that functionality with an external keyboard if possible.

Comment: What is the external keyboard that you use? If it doesn't have any designated multimedia keys for adjust screen brightness, you might have to use a third-party program/script to capture your desired combination and send the relevant key code to the OS.

Comment: @fragamemnon, I'm using a logitech k360 keyboard. Do you think I can achieve something like this with autohotkey?

Comment: Yeah, certainly. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/125563-universal-screen-brightness-changer/ should help.

Comment: It also may be worth checking out EasyMCC which would circumvent the hardware issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with RuSh. Some multimedia external keyboards do their own functions, so even though a lot of laptops use Fn+F5 & Fn-F6 for decreasing/increasing brightness your keyboard and it's respective drivers may utilize different keys. For example, my Microsoft Wireless Sculpt Ergonomic Keyboard has a completely different set of functions, so I have to rely on the options outlined in the previous post.